# How do I automatically approve a private endpoint request from front door?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-appservice, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

I am using Infrastructure-As-Code to create an app service, and a front door endpoint using a private endpoint. I do this with bicep templates.

Once created, I have to approve the private endpoint link in the UI.

How can I automatically approve this private endpoint request?
Is there a way to do this with a bicep deployment?

I use this bicep to create the origin, with the endpoint.

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: applicationName
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroup)
}

resource fdOrigin 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups/origins@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'fd-origin'
  parent: fdOriginGroup
  properties: {
    hostName: '${applicationName}.azurewebsites.net'
    httpPort: 80
    httpsPort: 443
    originHostHeader: '${applicationName}.azurewebsites.net'
    priority: 1
    weight: 1000
    sharedPrivateLinkResource: {
      groupId: 'sites'
      privateLinkLocation: 'EastUS2'
      requestMessage: 'Created by Deployment Pipeline'
      status: 'Approved'
      privateLink: {
        id: appService.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried setting the status to approved in the sharedPrivateLinkResource section, but it doesn't approve it. It's doesn't throw an error, but the link is still in Pending status.

I can approve it with the bicep below, but I have to hardcode the private link name. I can't find a way to get the private link name from the bicep above.

```
resource privateEndpointConnection 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'MyAppService/ecc50509-75b1-xxxx-92c9-62bebcececf3-13f6a331-6472-4497-bf94-67adda467e22'
  properties: {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
          status: 'Approved' 
          description: 'Approved by pipeline'
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can approve it using PowerShell command [`Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection`](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=490b3a9c41c47e45JmltdHM9MTY5Njk4MjQwMCZpZ3VpZD0zMGY1NDQzZi02NmJlLTYyYmYtMzM3NC01NjkzNjc1NjYzYTYmaW5zaWQ9NTIwOQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=30f5443f-66be-62bf-3374-5693675663a6&psq=Approve-AzPrivateEndpointConnection&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9sZWFybi5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2VuLXVzL3Bvd2Vyc2hlbGwvbW9kdWxlL2F6Lm5ldHdvcmsvYXBwcm92ZS1henByaXZhdGVlbmRwb2ludGNvbm5lY3Rpb24_dmlldz1henBzLTEwLjEuMA&ntb=1). @Don Chambers

Comment: Is this works for you? @DonChambers

Comment: could you share your bicep file please ? you can set auto approval on the `privateLinkServices`.  Also you can approve the privateEndpointConnections using this template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/privateendpointconnections?pivots=deployment-language-bicep. you just need to set the status as approved

Comment: See as well: https://broersma.dev/approve-private-endpoint-connections/

Comment: Can you share your bicep script to work on the issue. @DonChambers

Comment: @Jahnavi your powershell option worked.

Comment: @Thomas I couldn't use the bicep suggestion because there is no way to get the endpoint name when it's created. That approach only works when I manually get the name.

Comment: @Thomas I do define the endpoint when I create the origin. I can't approve the endpoint when I create it.
I've updated the post with the bicep.

Comment: Can I work on the powershell script and post as an answer! So that it will be benefit for others in future. @DonChambers

Comment: @thomas, I added it below as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once front-door deployment is completed, the private endpoint connections information are available on the webapp properties itself. You can verify that by running:

```
az rest --method get --uri <webapp-resource-id>?api-version=2022-09-01
```

You will see this section:

```json
"privateEndpointConnections": [
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/front-door-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myapp-bckwiz6zgci7k/privateEndpointConnections/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ...
  }
]
```

you can create a module to fetch the endpoint name:

```
// fetch-private-endpoint.bicep
param appName string
resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}
output name string = last(split(first(app.properties.privateEndpointConnections).id,'/'))
```

Then having a second module to approve the connection:

```
// approve-private-endpoint.bicep
param appName string
param endPointName string

resource app 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

resource privateEndpointConnection 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: app
  name: endPointName
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
      description: 'Approved by pipeline'
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your main template you can add that:

```
// Need to wait for front door deployment to be completed
module fetchPrivateEdnpointName 'modules/fetch-private-endpoint.bicep' = {
  name: 'fetch-private-endpoint'
  dependsOn: [
    fdOrigin
  ]
  params: {
    appName: appName
  }
}

module approvePrivateEndpoint 'modules/approve-private-endpoint.bicep' = {
  name: 'approve-private-endpoint'
  params: {
    appName: appName
    endPointName: fetchPrivateEdnpointName.outputs.name
  }
}
```