# How to automatically approve a private endpoint request from front door using bicep?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

Implemented the answer from Thomas on this question: [How do I automatically approve a private endpoint request from front door?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273621/how-do-i-automatically-approve-a-private-endpoint-request-from-front-door)

The bicep code seems to work accordingly but something strange is occurring.
On the initial run where the link does not exist yet, it get's created as it should and is also approved, but the bicep deployment does fail on the approve step with the following message:

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "target": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RGNAME>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<APPNAME>/privateEndpointConnections/774ab459-37e5-4bb8-9bc5-436408c864c1-e54d42d7-34ce-42df-b09d-456031a9016d",
    "message": "The response for resource had empty or invalid content."
    }
}
```

As mentioned, it does approve the connection and when the exact same bicep code is run again, it results in a succeeded deployment.

Any ideas?

Reviewed the bicep templates and also the successful results when redeploying, nothing seems to be out of order.

As requested some code:

Part of the code to get the link and approve it, this is part of a template that first creates the origins.

```
module getPrivateLink 'private-link/web-getPrivateLink.bicep' = [for (origin, index) in originArray: if(contains(origin, 'privateLink') && privateLinkOriginDetails[index].groupId == 'sites'){
  name: 'getLink-${origin.name}'
  params: {
    name: origin.privateLink.privateLinkResourceName
  }
  dependsOn: [
    origins
  ]
}]

module approveLink 'private-link/web-approveLink.bicep' = [for (origin, index) in originArray: if(contains(origin, 'privateLink') && privateLinkOriginDetails[index].groupId == 'sites'){
  name: 'approveLink-${origin.name}'
  params: {
    appName: origin.privateLink.privateLinkResourceName
    linkName: getPrivateLink[index].outputs.linkName
  }
}]
```

web-GetPrivateLink.bicep

```
param name string

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: name
}

output linkName string = last(split(first(appService.properties.privateEndpointConnections).id,'/'))
output resourceName string = name
```

web-approveLink.bicep

```
param appName string
param linkName string

resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

resource privateEndpointConnection 'Microsoft.Web/sites/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: appService
  name: linkName
  properties: {
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      status: 'Approved'
      description: 'Approved by pipeline'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same template ? Could you share the bicep files you're deploying please ?

Comment: @Thomas,

Since text was too long i've added your request to the initial question

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290882/19785512) by @[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas), I tried the similar approach to resolve your issue.

I was able to retrieve the connected private endpoint connection details with below CLI command as mentioned in the above reference.

```bash
az rest --method get --uri <appservice-resourceID>?api-version=xxxx
```

[image]

The displayed output contains the connection which I had in my app service.

Now coming to the bicep code, your code looks good to me.
Need to check below to avoid little conflicts.

As mentioned in the [Blog](https://jeroen-vdb.medium.com/azure-storage-account-in-a-virtual-network-the-response-for-resource-had-empty-or-invalid-content-a5984f5d9ff) | @ [Jeroen VdB](https://jeroen-vdb.medium.com/?source=post_page-----a5984f5d9ff--------------------------------), I got to know that when you are trying to link a endpoint which is presented in a virtual network (which was linked to the app service deployed), service endpoints have to be enabled under `virtual networks` resource.

```bash
"serviceEndpoints": [
                    {
                      "service": "Microsoft.Web"
                    }
            ]
```

Once it is enabled, I was able to deploy the resource successfully as shown below.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also add a resource deployment script to introduce and retrieve logs about delay before attempting to retrieve information about the approved connection.

*Reference template*: [`Microsoft.Resources/deployments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deployments?pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Comment: Hi, 

Unfortunately adding the serviceEndpoints does not work, I can confirm that the privateEndpointConnection is in Pending state before I approve it, but still the errors occur.

I also get inconsistent results when trying to approve multiple endpoints, one says "Invalid content" the other says "Internal server error" Nothing seems to be out of order.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? @ejer

Comment: Internal server error occurs when the environment is not properly configured. Have you checked it once. @ejer

Comment: Hi, Yes still facing the issue, currently in a support ticket with Microsoft, a call is scheduled to investigate will update when more information is available.

Comment: So the issue is not with the functionality you meant? It is with the default feature? @ejer